# What's the meaning of "Link Attribute" in database design?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a diagram. And I left only the tables on the diagram that interest me. Please, help me to understand, what's the meaning "LinkAttribute" in this case ? It's a separate table or it's a special key or what?
Tables "Country", "Lead" and "Event" I understand completely. But I noticed, that there's the same columns "start" and "end" (type of date) in three tables and in "LinkAttribute". How is it related?

[image]

It seems to me that "LinkAttribute" is not exactly a table, and it's not about foreign keys. But how to implement this "LinkAttribute" in SQL?

Comment: ... where/join   condition

Comment: @ScaisEdge I don't understand you. Do I need to create table "LinkAttribute"? And link in others tables by foreign keys?